# Spring boot azure functions doesnt start due to NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, maven

I'm building a couple of functions in order to have some cron jobs in Microsoft Azure.
However, this cronjobs need to edit the database, like doing a user of the day thing, where i select someone randomly from the db and set a flag to the db saying that that person is in fact the user of the day.
The problem is, when i start the spring boot app (as regular spring boot in eclipse or in command line as azure functions app) it has an exception that prevents the connection from the database.
Im using Azure CosmosDB's spring boot starter, (that i use in the main application and works).
This is the exception that i get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.http.HttpClient.createFixed(HttpClient.java:47)

The following method did not exist:

    reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider.fixed(Ljava/lang/String;IJLjava/time/Duration;)Lreactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider;

The method's class, reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/gonca/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty-core/1.0.1/reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar!/reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider: file:/C:/Users/gonca/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty-core/1.0.1/reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider
```

Since this is most likely a dependency error, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.scc</groupId>
    <artifactId>scc-functions</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>scc-functions</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.9.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <functionAppName>scc-47167-47316-47588-functions</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>westeurope</functionAppRegion>
        <subscriptionId>77718b4d-8b63-400b-ba08-08914f82af8d</subscriptionId>
        <functionPricingTier>B1</functionPricingTier>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
        <functionResourceGroup>scc-47167-47316-47588-functions</functionResourceGroup>
        <start-class>com.scc.SccFunctionsApplication</start-class>
        <spring.boot.wrapper.version>1.0.25.RELEASE</spring.boot.wrapper.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE</name>
                            <value>1</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~3</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME</name>
                            <value>java</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/azure
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.boot.wrapper.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Now, ive tried adding the azure spring bom, ive tried including a netty dependency directly, but nothing of that worked. How can i possibly fix this?

Comment: afaik there is not yet a Spring Cloud version compatible with Spring Boot 2.4.

Comment: I tried medling with that, but how do i do that? how do i find the compatible version? What version should i put in the <parent>?

Comment: I dont know how to just make it compatible. There is so much stuff in the pom that was in microsoft website that i have no clue on how to configure this in order to work

Comment: As stated there is no Spring Cloud version yet that is compatible. Downgrade Spring Boot to get a compatible version.

Comment: Downgrade how? in the dependencyManagement? to what version?

Comment: Find the version that is used by the Spring Cloud version you are using. But I suspect 2.3.6 should work. Also just copy-pasting a pom without knowing what is going in is probably a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: I know it s a bad idea, but since microsoft had a huge pom i didnt make much effort to undertand the plugin part